# Is there a way to style the signup and unsubscribe forms for a mailchimp list using Mailchimp API v3.0?

Tags: mailchimp

Through the mailchimp web interface, for a given list, you can use the form builder to customize the look of the signup form, as well as opt-in emails and thank you emails from mailchimp.

Is there a way to configure the styling of these forms using the mailchimp API?

Or even just a way to use the API to copy the styling configurations from one mailchimp list to another?